# AngularJS: Repeat and filter by number range

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to format a 'score' system. What my json returns is a 'title' and a 'score' - ideally I would like it to format something like this:

100--------

Title -- 99

Title -- 91

90--------

Title -- 89

Title -- 81

80-------- (etc etc)

I have made it so my score are in order from highest to lowest, but I don't know how to filter the ranges and somehow sneak in an extra table row for the main "100, 90, 80" count/header areas.

HTML Code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table class="table">
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in myData | orderBy:'title' | orderBy:'-score'">
    <td>{{x.title}}</td>
    <td>{{x.score}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("scores.json").then(function (response) {
  $scope.myData = response.data;
 });
});
```

I thought maybe a for loop or if statement would work, but I'm not sure how to fit that into angularjs's options/filters etc.

Comment: Inside your ngrepeat, you can have an ngif that checks if $index is divisible by 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this without applying any filter condition.but i have slightly changed your json format. check my jsfiddle here.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manoj348954/mkbwjo9m/2/)

and here is my code

Script

```
var myApp = angular.module('Application', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tabledata = [{
        title:"100",subhead:[{value:"99"},{value:"98"},{value:"97"}]
    }, {
        title:"90",subhead:[{value:"89"},{value:"88"},{value:"87"}]
    }, {
        title:"80",subhead:[{value:"79"},{value:"78"},{value:"77"}]
    }, {
        title:"70",subhead:[{value:"69"},{value:"68"},{value:"67"}]
    }];    

}]);
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="Application" ng-controller="myController">
    {{ tabledata }}
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="data in tabledata">
      <div id="data.title" class="title">
        {{data.title}}
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="subHeading in data.subhead" class="subhead"> 
        {{subHeading.value}}
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.title
{
  background-color:#ccc;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:24px;
  widht:100%;
  height:auto;

}
.subhead{
  background-color:#d7d7d7;  
  font-size:18px;
  widht:100%;
  height:auto;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

**Your HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="x in myData | orderBy:'title' | orderBy:'-score'" ng-if="x.score % 10 == 0">
        <td colspan="2">x.score -----------</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td>{{x.title}}</td>
        <td>{{x.score}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

If your score is a multiple of 10, it will display a section's title then it will display the title and the score